# Laravel Cash & Credit Card Report Groupby Day

Tags: laravel, laravel-10

```
0 => [
    id => 1,
    receipt_number => 1-1000,
    total_payment => 1000,
    created_at => 19.10.2023 22:02,
    payments => [
        0 => [
            name => "Cash",
            money_amount => 200
        ],
        1 => [
            name => "Card",
            money_amount => 500
        ]
        2 => [
            name => "Card",
            money_amount => 300
        ]
    ]
],
1 => [
    id => 2,
    receipt_number => 1-1001,
    total_payment => 500,
    created_at => 19.10.2023 22:25,
    payments => [
        0 => [
            name => "Cash",
            money_amount => 500
        ],
    ]
],
2 => [
    id => 3,
    receipt_number => 1-1002,
    total_payment => 200,
    created_at => 20.10.2023 09:25,
    payments => [
        0 => [
            name => "Card",
            money_amount => 200
        ],
    ]
],
3 => [
    id => 4,
    receipt_number => 1-1003,
    total_payment => 1200,
    created_at => 20.10.2023 11:42,
    payments => [
        0 => [
            name => "Card",
            money_amount => 200
        ],
        0 => [
            name => "Cash",
            money_amount => 1000
        ],
    ]
],
4 => [
    id => 5,
    receipt_number => 1-1004,
    total_payment => 2000,
    created_at => 21.10.2023 19:25,
    payments => [
        0 => [
            name => "Card",
            money_amount => 2000
        ],
    ]
],
```

Hello, I have an array value same as above. I would like to modify it same as below. Each key will have total amount of cash and card grouped by day.

```
0 => [
    Cash => [
        date => 19.10.2023,
        total_amount => 700,
    ],
    Card => [
        date => 19.10.2023,
        total_amount => 800,
    ],
],
1 => [
    Cash => [
        date => 20.10.2023,
        total_amount => 1000,
    ],
    Card => [
        date => 20.10.2023,
        total_amount => 400,
    ],
],
2 => [
    Cash => [
        date => 21.10.2023,
        total_amount => 0,
    ],
    Card => [
        date => 21.10.2023,
        total_amount => 2000,
    ],
],
```

I ve tried many way to do it but I cannot grouped it as well. This is from shop sales array values and I would like to get Daily Cash and credit report. Which way is the best for it? thanks for your support.

Comment: Your starting data and ending data do not match in totals. Is the ending data the totals for cash and card for that day, based on the starting data?

Comment: every order has its own payment data in values and payment can be done with more than once.

For example;
Customers had bill with 100 USD expenses. But 2 people will share this payment with 30 USD AND 70 USD. First person paid 30 USD Cash, and another person paid 70 usd by card.(Split the payment). And im saving it in array object in array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you would need to create a separate function to do this transformation of data. I don't think there is a specific Laravel/PHP function which can do this complex condensation of data.

Here is what I have come up with, but I am not sure if it works 100% so please test it out:

```php
function transformSalesData($data) {
    // Initialize an empty result array
    $result = [];

    // Iterate through the original data
    foreach ($data as $entry) {
        $date = substr($entry['created_at'], 0, 10); // Extract the date portion
        $payments = $entry['payments'];

        // Initialize or update the Cash and Card totals for the date
        $result[$date]['Cash']['date'] = $date;
        $result[$date]['Cash']['total_amount'] += array_sum(array_column(array_filter($payments, function ($payment) {
            return $payment['name'] === 'Cash';
        }), 'money_amount'));

        $result[$date]['Card']['date'] = $date;
        $result[$date]['Card']['total_amount'] += array_sum(array_column(array_filter($payments, function ($payment) {
            return $payment['name'] === 'Card';
        }), 'money_amount'));
    }

    // Reindex the result array
    $result = array_values($result);

    return $result;
}

// Transform the data using the function
$transformedData = transformSalesData($data); // where $data is your starting data
```